# Authentication request to /j_spring_security_check 404 Error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

With the security configuration below, making a post request to /j_spring_security_check throws a 404 error. Could someone help me point out what I'm doing wrong?

**security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Areas of the application which require no secuirty to visit -->

    <security:http security="none" pattern="/login/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/handler/**" />

    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login/"
            default-target-url="/login/successful_login.html"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
            <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:logout />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="protrackAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="protrackAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.example.security.ProtrackAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <description>ProtrackEntities</description>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/ptentities-spring.xml
        /WEB-INF/ptentities-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>exportHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myersinfosys.protrack.server.handlers.FileExportHandler</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>exportHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/exportHandler</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gwt-rpc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gwt-rpc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rpc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the request error:

> Remote Address:127.0.0.1:59322 Request
>   URL:http://127.0.0.1:59322/j_spring_security_check Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:404 Not Found

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using Spring Security version 4.0

I just upgraded from Spring Security 3.2.3 to 4.0.1 and it looks like the default URLs for the login and logout handlers have changed from **/j_spring_security_check** to **/login** and **/j_spring_security_logout** to **/logout** respectively.

It also looks like the URL you are using is missing the application context component part of the path, which is usually the name of your web application. It should look more like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:59322/YourWebapp/j_spring_security_check
```

or for later Spring Security versions:

```
http://127.0.0.1:59322/YourWebapp/login
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can still configure login/logout URL, so that you existing apps that used old spring security will work as is, without need to update `/j_spring_security_check -> /login` and `/j_spring_security_logout -> logout`. In Java based configuration it will look similar to this: `@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { http.formLogin().usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check"); http.logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout"); }` You just remap urls to old ones.