# 404 on j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security to create a simple login system. When I post from the login form, I get a 404 on j_spring_security_check.

Here's my spring security:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/dashboard/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="pass" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/mp" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And my login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false)   String error,
                        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
if (error != null) {
  modelAndView.addObject("error", "Are you sure you got the correct username/password....");
}

if (logout != null) {
  modelAndView.addObject("msg", "We are sorry to see you go....");
}

modelAndView.setViewName(Views.LOGIN_VIEW);

return modelAndView;
 }
}
```

And my login view:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<spring:url value="resources/styles/mundane.css" var="coreCss" />
<c:url value="j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl" />
<link href="${coreCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<c:if test="${not empty error}">
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>Oh snap!</strong> ${error}.
</div>
</c:if>
  <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>Oh snap!</strong> ${msg}
  </div>
 </c:if>

<form name='loginForm'
  action="${loginUrl}" method='POST'>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" />
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
       value="${_csrf.token}" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `loginUrl` should be `/login` (and not `j_spring_security...`)

Comment: If by any chance, you're using spring security 4.0+, you should send your authentication request to `/login`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication request to /j\_spring\_security\_check 404 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650089/authentication-request-to-j-spring-security-check-404-error)